# Removing added layers using Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, layers, remove

I add polygon data on the Leaflet map by selecting parameters: travel_mode and travel_time from the form control and clicking a button "btnGenerate". This button click function is working as expected: it adds as many polygons as it is clicked. Say I click the button 3 times, with 3 different parameters of travel_mode and travel_time, it adds 3 different polygons on the map. Now when I click another button which invokes the function "removeTraveltime", it only removes the last added polygons. First 2 polygons are still on the map. My aim is to remove all 3 added polygons from the map with one click of the remove button.  I am not sure how to implement that.
My code is as below:

```
var ttPoly;
$("#btnGenerate").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
            url: 'php/traveltime.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data:{eno:enos,
                  travel_mode: $("#travelmode").val(),
                  travel_time: $("#traveltime").val()                            
            },
            success: callbackTT
    });
    
        function callbackTT(response){                
                ttPoly = L.geoJSON(JSON.parse(response), {forEach:function(ttPoly){
                         var poly =L.polygon(ttPoly.geometry.coordinates);
                }}); 
        
                ttPoly.setStyle({
                    color:'purple',
                    fillOpacity:0.4
                });
                $("#dlgTravelTime").hide();
                ttPoly.addTo(mymap);   
        };               
});
    
function removeTraveltime(enos){
        if(ttPoly){
             mymap.removeLayer(ttPoly);                        
        } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only one `var ttPoly` for all your created polygons, so at any given moment it points only to the last created polygon.

One way of resolve this problem is to have array `var ttPolyActive = []` to which you add every created poly and iterate through it when you want to remove them.

Your code could then look something like this:

```
var ttPolyActive = [];
$("#btnGenerate").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'php/traveltime.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data:{eno:enos,
      travel_mode: $("#travelmode").val(),
      travel_time: $("#traveltime").val()                            
    },
    success: callbackTT
  });
  
  function callbackTT(response) {                
    var ttPoly = L.geoJSON(JSON.parse(response), {forEach:function(ttPoly){
       var poly =L.polygon(ttPoly.geometry.coordinates);
    }}); 

    ttPoly.setStyle({
      color:'purple',
      fillOpacity:0.4
    });
    $("#dlgTravelTime").hide();
    ttPoly.addTo(mymap);
    ttPolyActive.push(ttPoly);
  };               
});
    
function removeTraveltime(enos) {
  ttPolyActive.forEach(function(ttPoly) {
    mymap.removeLayer(ttPoly);                        
  });
  ttPolyActive = [];
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works perfect. While I was playing with the code, I also managed to get the desired result with the use of  layergroup. I will post my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to do it this way. Posting here as an alternative.

```
var ttPoly;
var ttLayerGroup = new L.LayerGroup();
$("#btnGenerate").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
            url: 'php/traveltime.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data:{eno:enos,
                  travel_mode: $("#travelmode").val(),
                  travel_time: $("#traveltime").val()                            
            },
            success: callbackTT
    });
    
        function callbackTT(response){                
                ttPoly = L.geoJSON(JSON.parse(response), {forEach:function(ttPoly){
                         var poly =L.polygon(ttPoly.geometry.coordinates);
                }}); 
        
                ttPoly.setStyle({
                    color:'purple',
                    fillOpacity:0.4
                });
                $("#dlgTravelTime").hide();
                ttLayerGroup.addLayer(ttPoly);
                ttLayerGroup.addTo(mymap); 
            
        };               
});
    
function removeTraveltime(enos){
    ttLayerGroup.clearLayers();
}
```